# What is the source of this "No Hits" GA notification when using GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have done the following:

- Added GTM tracking snippet
- Set up a GA (UA) tag of type 'Pageview'
- Published version

I am getting data in, (Users, Sessions and Pageviews and Real-Time)

But, also receiving this notification in the GA UI:

[image]

"**No Hits** Property [MYPROPERTYID] is not receiving hits."

All I have been able to find suggests that maybe the tracking code is somehow "broken", but the code on the page seems to be identical to that which is given by GTM.

Also, as mentioned, data seems to be coming in fine.

How can I beat this error? Is there something I have neglected to do in my workflow that is leaving GA unsatisfied (such as an additional GA tag of some kind)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you just very recently create the Account or Property in Google Analytics? It may take up to 24 hours before the data is completely processed, which would explain that Notification.

Comment: Thanks! It was more than 24 hours, but it did go away after a while on its own. The issue now says "Resolved".

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you ever find yourself in a similar situation, you might also want to click on the "Check again" link of that Notification item from time to time, to try and speed up the refresh.

Comment: @Drewdavid please help meee. I have the same issue and i am struck
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980461/why-event-hits-are-not-logged-on-my-google-analytics