# reywood/meteor-iron-router-ga not working with mobile app cordova for Google Analytics

Tags: meteor, google-analytics, iron-router, google-analytics-sdk

I am using reywood/meteor-iron-router-ga package for my Google analytics but i do not know why events or Real time events are not logged from mobile app. I did simple configurations for this but not worked. I also used Google Analytics debugger to detect the problem but it looks fine

- Link Analytics and Search Console -> RESOLVED
- Bad Default URL                   -> RESOLVED

  [image: Google Analytics Debug]

This is the output of any event click on my app. I also try to replace reywood/meteor-iron-router-ga with simple JavaScript [Analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events?authuser=1#overview) but still no benefit.

```
ga('send', 'event', {
            eventCategory: Category,
            eventAction: Action,
            eventLabel: Label
        });
```

settings.json

```
"ga": {
        "id": "UA-75464623-1",
        "create": {
            "cookieDomain": "dev.goodatlas.com",
            "cookieName": "my_ga_cookie",
            "cookieExpires": 3600
        }
    }
```

Cordova Settings for mobile in mobile-config.js

```
App.accessRule('*.google-analytics.com/*');
```

Even on Google Tag Assistant it shows me the data but no display on Google Analytics Real Time or on event Behavior
[image]
Can any body tell me what i am doing wrong here.....

I already spent too much time on this

Comment: I noticed that you are setting cookie domain, but at the same time the location is `localhost`. Might be something to check out.

Comment: @nyuen Image updated ... getting the same issue with live website as well 'dev.goodatlas.com'

Answer (score 1):

I am also having the same issue. When I run the app I can see the realtime tracking, but when I build the app and then run it doesn't work.

As per the package we need to provide public settings of Google Analytics in `settings.json` file. I've solved it by passing the `--mobile-settings settings.json` while building the app and it works.